# Просьба пояснить постановку знака препинания

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> *Если я живу в Англии, я буду говорить «I have got a car». Ну, а если я
>   американец, то буду использовать просто «have» (—) I have a car.*

Объясните, пожалуйста, поподробнее постановку данного тире.

Answer (score 3):

Сначала уберём запятую после *ну*, так как *ну* здесь частица, а не междометие.

Тире действительно можно поставить, хотя ожидается двоеточие. Тире заменяет отсутствующее слово "например".

***Если я живу в Англии, я буду говорить «I have got a car». Ну а если я американец, то буду использовать просто «have» — I have a car.***

[**Двоеточие — тире**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189) (Розенталь)

> ...В «конкурентной борьбе» двоеточия с тире «победителем» нередко выходит тире. Это явление отмечается многими исследователями, которые считают, что «в целом тире — знак более свободный, заходящий и во владения двоеточия»[36] и что «выявляется тенденция к вытеснению в ряде случаев двоеточия знаком тире»[37]. Объяснить это можно особым статусом тире среди других знаков препинания: «В настоящее время тире очень употребительный и многофункциональный знак препинания. Он выполняет как грамматические (чисто синтаксические), так и эмоционально-экспрессивные функции; особенно широко используется он в последнем качестве в художественной литературе».